# Prepopulate fields in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have a webservice that returns me some array data like this:

```
[
    {
      "blocoId": "22222",
      "picture": "https://scontent.fgru5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/26239637_564903593861404_856562314194_n.jpg?oh=798138761d9aa1a4dad08ebd1f1b7e1f&oe=5AE9E6F4",
      "latitude": -23.5533489,
      "bloco_name": "Bla bla bla lba",
      "longitude": -46.6137802
    },
    {
      "blocoId": "223123",
      "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25498441_1563972223683785_1245115263357_n.jpg?oh=cf3a76633cfc77e1d1c3429a4135207d&oe=5AECA161",
      "latitude": -23.528079836998,
      "bloco_name": "asd asd asd ad asd",
      "longitude": -46.669401475534
    }
  ]
```

The elements are shown in a list, if the user clicks on it, (s)he navigates to a detailed screen.
While the service is fetching the rest of the details from the api, I'd like to prepopulate the fields that I have.
The final json is:

```
{
  "blocoId": "324234",
  "is_draft": 0,
  "longitude": -46.6137802,
  "start_time": "2018-01-25T16:00:00-0200",
  "end_time": "2018-01-28T23:00:00-0200",
  "picture": "https://scontent.fgru5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/26239637_56490355355612856562314194_n.jpg?oh=798138761d9aa1a4dad08ebd1f1b7e1f&oe=5AE9E6F4",
  "latitude": -23.5533489,
  "bloco_name": "asdasdasd"
}
```

My code so far:

```
class BloquinhoDetail extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.preset(this.props.navigation.state.params.bloquinho)
    this.props.fetchBloquinhoDetail(this.props.navigation.state.params.bloquinho.blocoId)
  }

  render() {
    const startTime = this.props.bloquinho ? Moment(this.props.bloquinho.start_time).format('lll') : ''
    const outTime = this.props.bloquinho && this.props.bloquinho.end_time ? startTime + ' - ' + Moment(this.props.bloquinho.end_time).format('kk:mm') : startTime
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{ uri: this.props.bloquinho ? this.props.bloquinho.picture: '' }} style={{ height: 220 }} resizeMode='stretch' />
        ...
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    bloquinho: state.bloquinhoDetail.bloquinho,
    fetching: state.bloquinhoDetail.fetching,
    error: state.bloquinhoDetail.error
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchBloquinhoDetail: (id) => dispatch(BloquinhoDetailsAction.bloquinhoDetailRequest(id)),
    preset: (bloquinho) => dispatch(BloquinhoDetailsAction.bloquinhoDetailPreset(bloquinho.bloco_name, bloquinho.blocoId, bloquinho.picture))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BloquinhoDetail)
```

and my redux file:

```
const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  bloquinhoDetailRequest: ['blocoId'],
  bloquinhoDetailPreset: ['bloco_name', 'blocoId', 'picture'],
  bloquinhoDetailSuccess: ['bloquinho'],
  bloquinhoDetailFailure: null,
})

export const BloquinhoDetailTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  bloquinho: null,
  fetching: null,
  error: null,
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */

export const request = (state) =>
  state.merge({ fetching: true })

export const preset = (state, action) => {
    const { bloco_name, blocoId, picture } = action
    return state.merge({ fetching: true, bloquinho: { bloco_name, blocoId, picture }})
}

export const success = (state, action) => {
  const { bloquinho } = action
  return state.merge({ fetching: false, error: null, bloquinho })
}

export const failure = (state) =>
  state.merge({ fetching: false, error: true, bloquinho: null })

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.BLOQUINHO_DETAIL_REQUEST]: request,
  [Types.BLOQUINHO_DETAIL_PRESET]: preset,
  [Types.BLOQUINHO_DETAIL_SUCCESS]: success,
  [Types.BLOQUINHO_DETAIL_FAILURE]: failure,
})
```

The problems I'm facing:
When I click on 1 card, return and click on the 2nd, the data from the 1st one seems to be cached (the object is not cleaned up once I leave the screen).
Second, the first time the render function gets called, I have no value from the preset returned, giving me "source.uri should not be empty".

What is the best way to achieve this prepopulate thing in RN?

Thanks!

Comment: 2. It's a common pattern for props to initially be empty in React components. You have to modify your render function to take this into account. For example, don't render anything at all if a required prop is missing: `{this.props.bloquinho && <ScrollView ..>...}` or `if !this.props.bloquinho  return null`

Comment: You mention clicking on a card. Is there a click handler somewhere in another file? Showing that code here may help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after some trial and errors I came up with this:

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.bloquinho)
      return null;

    const startTime = Moment(this.props.bloquinho.start_time).format('lll')
    const outTime = this.props.bloquinho.end_time ? startTime + ' - ' + Moment(this.props.bloquinho.end_time).format('kk:mm') : startTime
...
```

And it worked!